# How do I give facility to other to login with my service using oauth 2.0

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am developing one app for third party and need login facility of my application. Suppose my application name is Howdy and the app i am developing is Guider.

So in the Guider, I need to give facility login with Howdy. So Guider is giving me form to register the app. so now I have

```
Authorize url : https://guider.howdy.com/authorize   
Client ID: guider
Cliend secret: abcd-1234-efgh-7896
Token Url: https://guider.howdy.com/token
Endpoint: https://guider.howdy.com
```

So i went to [This](http://tutorialspage.com/simple-oauth2-example-using-php-curl/) link and follow the instructions but failed to get the result.

I read lot of document and unable to get any suitable example so that i can do it with Oauth 2.0.

**Unable to understand the following:**

1: Is there any third party library i need to install on my server to perform the Oauth 2.0. If yes, then which one?
2:What kind of code do i need to write into the authorize and token folder?
3: And how do I redirect the application back to the app?

I am kind of very new as a developer, reading document is not exaclty helping me here. please suggest with suitable example.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own OAuth client where you create and manage access credentials for users? There are libraries for PHP here: https://oauth.net/code/php/

Comment: yes.. Howdy is my service and guider is third party client... so basically in the guider app.. login button will say Login with Howdy

Comment: Your given link is not working

Comment: I see that now. You can at least visit Google's cached version: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BZHK6-PtPhAJ:https://oauth.net/code/php/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us